# Wowway internet service drops connection frequently?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection, cable-modem

Our Wowway internet service keeps dropping out and I looked at the modem logs and see messages like this:

```
 Sep 06 2018 20:45:01   3-Critical  R02.0   No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=94:62:69:f0:93:33;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:6b:be:4a;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
```

Anyone know what that means?  It happens about every 2-3 hours and the outage lasts for about 1-2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is assuming your connection is a cable modem connected to a DOCSIS network.

You should disconnect all set top boxes, and disconnect all splitters in the way of the modem. Create a "home-run" from the modem to the feeder line (aerial or underground) coming into the property.

If you no longer experience drop-outs, you probably have a failing splitter or set-top box creating noise on the inside wiring. You can add the boxes and splitters back in one by one to determine which device is causing it.

T1 - T3 usually labeled "severe" or "critical" in the modem logs are a indication of a street level signal repeater, or TDMA-mux device starting to fail on the street.

If you continue to get these errors after trying to troubleshoot, you should notify the ISP. Make sure you mention the "T" based errors, it will create a street level dispatch to get it fixed.

Regards,